# NSMutableDictionary thread safety

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a question on thread safety while using `NSMutableDictionary`.

The main thread is reading data from `NSMutableDictionary` where:

- key is `NSString`
- value is `UIImage`

An asynchronous thread is writing data to above dictionary (using `NSOperationQueue`)

How do I make the above dictionary thread safe?

Should I make the `NSMutableDictionary` property `atomic`? Or do I need to make any additional changes?

`@property(retain) NSMutableDictionary *dicNamesWithPhotos;`

Comment: I'm no expert on multithreading, but I do know that the "atomic" flag (the default for @synthesize'd accessors) makes no guarantees of thread safety. I did think the same thing when I first read about it, though.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`NSMutableDictionary` isn't designed to be thread-safe data structure, and simply marking the property as `atomic`, doesn't ensure that the underlying data operations are actually performed atomically (in a safe manner).

To ensure that each operation is done in a safe manner, you would need to guard each operation on the dictionary with a lock:

```
// in initialization
self.dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// create a lock object for the dictionary
self.dictionary_lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];


// at every access or modification:
[object.dictionary_lock lock];
[object.dictionary setObject:image forKey:name];
[object.dictionary_lock unlock];
```

You should consider rolling your own `NSDictionary` that simply delegates calls to NSMutableDictionary while holding a lock:

```
@interface SafeMutableDictionary : NSMutableDictionary
{
    NSLock *lock;
    NSMutableDictionary *underlyingDictionary;
}

@end

@implementation SafeMutableDictionary

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
        underlyingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
   [lock_ release];
   [underlyingDictionary release];
   [super dealloc];
}

// forward all the calls with the lock held
- (retval_t) forward: (SEL) sel : (arglist_t) args
{
    [lock lock];
    @try {
        return [underlyingDictionary performv:sel : args];
    }
    @finally {
        [lock unlock];
    }
}

@end
```

Please note that because each operation requires waiting for the lock and holding it, it's not quite scalable, but it might be good enough in your case.

If you want to use a proper threaded library, you can use [TransactionKit library](http://transactionkit.sourceforge.net/) as they have `TKMutableDictionary` which is a multi-threaded safe library.  I personally haven't used it, and it seems that it's a work in progress library, but you might want to give it a try.

Comment: This looks like a great method but I can't get it to compile. I'm getting `"expected ')' before 'retval_t'"` on the line `- (retval_t) forward: (SEL) sel : (arglist_t) args` Any ideas?

Comment: Fabulous answer.  Now obsolete.  Use a queue instead.  I have a dead simple serialized dictionary somewhere.  I should post it.  Message forwarding is slow and fragile.

Comment: Follow-up to bbum's comment. There's a useful write-up on using GCD concurrent queues with NSMutableDictionary on Mike Ash's blog here: http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html

Comment: @bbum did you ever manage to post a example of your serialised dictionary?

Comment: How about using @sychronized to make it safe?

Comment: I agree with @AllenLin's comment, I find `@synchronized` to be more convenient than trying to explicitly lock/unlock.

Comment: Agreed with @allenlinli, this is essentially what `@synchronized` does for you for free since we are just locking access to the dictionary and not discerning if it's a get/set operation.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays you'd probably go for `@synchronized(object)` instead.

```
...
@synchronized(dictionary) {
    [dictionary setObject:image forKey:name];
}
...
@synchronized(dictionary) {
    [dictionary objectForKey:key];
}
...
@synchronized(dictionary) {
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
}
```

No need for the `NSLock` object any more

Comment: isnt this same as @prooerty (atomic) dictionary?

Comment: no, this would mean that replacing the dictionary with a whole new instance is atomic. Not changing one element in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

after a little bit of research I want to share with you this article :

Using collection classes safely with multithreaded applications
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2059.html

It looks like notnoop's answer may not be a solution after all. From threading perspective it is ok, but there are some critical subtleties. I will not post here a solution but I guess that there is a good one in this article.

Comment: +1 for noticing that locking isn't enough in this case. I was bitten by this once as well, the `[[[dict objectForKey:key] retain] autorelease]` "trick" really is necessary in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: That link is now broken, and the technote is from 2002. You might be better off with https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html.

Comment: -1 For what is almost (but not quite, thus avoiding flagging,) a link only answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have two options to using nsmutabledictionary.

One is:

```
NSLock* lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
[lock lock];
[object.dictionary setObject:image forKey:name];
[lock unlock];
```

Two is:

```
//Let's assume var image, name are setup properly
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{ 
        [object.dictionary setObject:image forKey:name];
});
```

I dont know why some people want to overwrite setting and getting of mutabledictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Even the answer is correct, there is an elegant and different solution:

```
- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.isolation.%p", [self class], self];
    self.isolationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([label UTF8String], NULL);

    label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.work.%p", [self class], self];
    self.workQueue = dispatch_queue_create([label UTF8String], NULL);
}
return self;
}
//Setter, write into NSMutableDictionary
- (void)setCount:(NSUInteger)count forKey:(NSString *)key {
key = [key copy];
dispatch_async(self.isolationQueue, ^(){
    if (count == 0) {
        [self.counts removeObjectForKey:key];
    } else {
        self.counts[key] = @(count);
    }
});
}
//Getter, read from NSMutableDictionary
- (NSUInteger)countForKey:(NSString *)key {
__block NSUInteger count;
dispatch_sync(self.isolationQueue, ^(){
    NSNumber *n = self.counts[key];
    count = [n unsignedIntegerValue];
});
return count;
}
```

The copy is important when using thread unsafe objects, with this you could avoid the possible error because of unintended release of the variable. No need for thread safe entities.

If more queue would like to use the NSMutableDictionary declare a private queue and change the setter to:

```
self.isolationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([label UTF8String], DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

- (void)setCount:(NSUInteger)count forKey:(NSString *)key {
key = [key copy];
dispatch_barrier_async(self.isolationQueue, ^(){
    if (count == 0) {
        [self.counts removeObjectForKey:key];
    } else {
        self.counts[key] = @(count);
    }
});
}
```

**IMPORTANT!**

You have to set an own private queue without it the *dispatch_barrier_sync* is just a simple *dispatch_sync*

Detailed explanation is in this [marvelous blog article](https://www.objc.io/issues/2-concurrency/low-level-concurrency-apis/).

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you might use the [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache) class. The documentation claims that it's thread safe:

> You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different threads without having to lock the cache yourself.

Here is [article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/caching-in-swift/) that describes quite useful tricks related to `NSCache`