# Objective-C: Forwarding messages in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, forwarding

Is it possible to use "Forwarding" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Forwarding) in iOS?

I tried the following code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986736/nsmutabledictionary-thread-safety/1986879#1986879):

```
- (retval_t) forward: (SEL) sel : (arglist_t) args
```

But I get an error message:

> error: expected ')' before 'retval_t'

So I read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Forwarding) and try:

```
- (retval_t)forward:(SEL)sel args:(arglist_t) args
```

But I got the same error message...

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to import something?

---

@bbum: I try to create a thread safe NSMutableArray and want to use the code I found here:
[NSMutableDictionary thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986736/nsmutabledictionary-thread-safety/1986879#1986879)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Forwarding based implementations are exceedingly uncommon and generally to be entirely avoided.

Comment: Try replacing `retval_t` with `id`.

Comment: @bbum: I try to create a thread safe NSMutableArray and want to use the code I linked in my question

Comment: Use a queue instead and serialize access via the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. What you're seeing there is the GNU variant of Objective-C, which is slightly different from the Apple variant.

You want to use `-forwardInvocation:` rather than `-forward::` or `-forward:args:`. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html for more info on how to do it with iOS.

Comment: That'll work, but you really *really **really** don't want to write software that relies on message forwarding of this nature unless it is unavoidable, which it is in all but the rarest of circumstances.

Comment: @bbum's right, of course--forwarding is Deep Magic and to be avoided unless no other option exists. I don't think I've found a need to implement it in years.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pattern I use for iOS forwardInvocation (message forwarding):

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    if ([self.recipient respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.recipient];
    }
    else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}
```

It is important to note that the return value of the message that’s forwarded is automatically returned to the original sender.