# setValuesForKeysWithDictionary in NSMutableDictionary is Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a method `updateTraits` in which I try to update the variable `traits` by using `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` and during this, the crash is happening.

`traits` is defined as shown below:

`@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, NSObject*>* traits;`

`UpdateTraits` is defined as shown below:

```
    - (void)updateTraits:(RSTraits *)traits {
    if(traits == nil) {
        traits = [[RSTraits alloc] init];
        traits.anonymousId = [preferenceManager getAnonymousId];
        [_traits removeAllObjects];
    }
     // crash is happening on this line here
    [_traits setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[traits dict]];
   }
```

Note: I am trying to call the `updateTraits` method from a background thread.

Can anyone point out what exactly I am doing wrong? Thanks in Advance.

Crash message: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

[image: Crash Description]

Comment: what is the crash?

Comment: it seems to me that (nonatomic, readwrite) results in unsafe_unretained property. Therefore _traits may simply be released. Try to make it (nonatomic, strong) and I bet 10 dollars the crash will be gone

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, Updated the question with info related to crash

Comment: You are on a different thread, could it be a concurrency issue?

Comment: Also tried making it to (nonatomic strong) but the issue isn't resolved. 
Yeah this could be a concurrency issue.

Comment: Does this crash if you run it on the main thread?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash on main thread

Comment: Then you'll need to either perform your operations on the main thread, or use a lock. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986879/725628

Comment: This is also useful information about [thread safety](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html)

Comment: Thank you for sharing them @EmilioPelaez. Will check them and post the results here